# Creating custom soap object in WCF XML serialization

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, xml-serialization

I am trying to create a SOAP object from WCF by XML serialization, For that am facing issue like some serialization doesn't met my expected output. I want to create a same WSDL file to support my old clients.

This is what I am getting soap request:

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <areStatusComplete xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <listIds>
        <string>12258</string>
        <string>478526</string>
      </listIds>
    </areStatusComplete>
  </s:Body>
```

Expected output is :

```
 <soap:Body>
    <ns1:areStatusComplete xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
      <listIds>88355</listIds>
      <listIds>88356</listIds>
    </ns1:areStatusComplete>
  </soap:Body>
```

C# code for data contract is:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "areStatusComplete", WrapperNamespace = "", IsWrapped = true)]
    public class areStatusComplete
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("listIds", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
        public string[] listIds { get; set; }


        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "", Order = 1)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string system;

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "", Order = 2)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string user;

        public areStatusComplete ()
        {
        }

        public areStatusComplete (string[] listIds, string system, string user)
        {
            this.listIds = listIds;
            this.system = system;
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
```

Service Contract code:

```
[OperationContract]
        areStatusCompleteResponse areStatusComplete (string[] listIds, string system, string user);
```

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Let us know the exact error message. 
from what i see it is expecting an array of listIds a custom C# class with the name listids needs to be created, and that needs to be a inner property of areStatusComplete class

```
public class areStatusComplete 
{
  public ListIds listIds {..}

}
```

Comment: we are getting the output without any error but output format is not getting what we expected